# How to center a form in the middle of bootstrap container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to give my form with one email input field and a button which is an image. My button and an input are aligned side by side. I want to center my form in the middle of the bootstrap container class, but nothing that I have tried has worked. I gave my form a width and margin:0 auto, but it didn't help at all.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="text-box-two">
            <span id="notification">BE NOTIFIED WHEN WE LAUNCH:</span>
        </div>
            <form class="well email-form form-inline" id="emailForm" name="sendEmail" novalidate="" method="post">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email-address" type="email" placeholder="ENTER EMAIL ADDRESS" required="" data-validation-required-message=" "/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group button">
                            <input type="image" src="images/tree.png" name="submitEmail" class="button"/>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.well.email-form{
background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
border: none !important;
border-radius: 1px !important;
}
#emailForm{
width:1115px;
margin:0 auto;
}
.form-group{
float:left;
}
#emailForm{
margin:0 auto;
}
.form-control{
height:102px;
border-radius:1px;
font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: could you link us to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You could try wrapping the form in `<div class='row'><div class='col-lg-12 text-justify'></div></div>`

Comment: is it fine??? http://jsfiddle.net/wzr4crfr/13/

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap framework to do this. Have a look at **[offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)** in the docs.

Try this in your container above.

```
<div class="container col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
```

Here's a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/bojLrrvz/)** with it working.